# what's the difference between ways to parameterize ngrx selector

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

in ngrx, there are 2 ways(see following code) to parameterize a selector.

**Question:** what's the difference between them?

```js
const getUser1 = () =>
  createSelector(
    getEntities,
    (state, props) => state[props.id]
  );

const getUser2 = id =>
  createSelector(
    getEntities,
    state => state[id]
  );
```

I think memoization works fine in both.

and article below says....

> If the parameter doesn’t change over time we can use a factory function
>   https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

ok. these selectors are used as follows.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-container',
  template: ``
})
export class UserContainerComponent {
  user1$ = this.store.pipe(select(getUser1(), { id: 1 }))
  user2$ = this.store.pipe(select(getUser2(2)))

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
}
```

in both case (`getUser1()` and `getUser2(2)`), factory functions are evaluated when intializing the class(so, parameter will not be changed for both selector).
I couldn't find the difference in this case....

when is `getUser1` useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre v6.2 it wasn't possible to use the first selector example, so the only way to pass props to a selector was to create a factory function.

Both examples in the question do exactly the same.

The difference would be that  `props` would be passed down to **all** selectors in `createSelector`, the factory function would not.